# Bluetooth connecting request problem in higher versions of android

Tags: java, android-studio, sdk, version, android-bluetooth

I developed one app minSDKversion = 21 and maxSDKversion = 33
bluetooth is enabled as per my java code upto android version 10 while am running my code in android version 12 and above its not working. My app suddendly crashing, give me the solution How to solve

I was updated the dependencies and also updated the Androidmanifest.xml file but still facing same issue